# Laravel overloading the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.5

I updated my laravel 4.2 project to 5.5, and swited the php 5.6 version to 7.2. When I try to switch my production server to the new one, with the exact same configurations (values, php fpm and nginx), my MYSQL 5.6 database (with 16 processors) starts to overloading and executing some about 200+ threads per time (the old executes arround 16 threads), knocking down my server after some minutes. Has anyone ever had this problem? Or know how to handle it?

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and find out more.

Comment: I searched for the differences between those versions and the common problemns but I didn't find answers... But in my searchs I found one lib (https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching) that cache eloquent models of laravel in Redis, and it saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the exactly answer to these problemns and why laravel 5.5 is overloading the mysql database and the 4.2 don't. But I found a cache lib of eloquent models in Laravel that give a high performance result using one redis database.

The lib in question is: github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching

It promises a huge performance improvement.

Comment: Good find. This is why I strongly recommend people use frameworks: You can immediately and easily leverage huge amounts of community code.